# Python, alternative to not in list

Tags: python, list, boolean

I've seen lots of questions regarding 'not in list', but few alternatives to the solution I need or issue I have which i thought would be the normal use case?

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
while list:
        q1 = int(input("Enter number: "))
        if q1 in list:
            list.remove(q1)
            print("match")
        elif q1 not in list:
          print("No match")
else:
  print("end")
```

I understand the logic is basically saying If true = true then true which doesn't work, but you also can't say "if q1 in not list:" either. So if you want to check if q1 is not in list, then how do you do that?

---

Well, maybe I just figured this out.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
while list:
        q1 = int(input("Enter number: "))
        if q1 in list:
            list.remove(q1)
            print("match")
        elif not q1 in list:
          print("No match")
else:
  print("end")
```

Seems to do exactly what I want and what I've seen other people trying to do. I hope this is correct.

however, now I want to do list1 and list2 but:

```
        elif not q1 in list1 and list2:
          print("No match")
```

does not work.

Comment: Exactly as you did in your code, even though a simple `else` statement would be sufficient here. You can also write `if not(q1 in list):` but it's judged _less pythonic_

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what the problem is? The code is more or less fine, although you can just replace your `elif...:` with just `else`, since if `q1 in list` is True, then `q1 not in list` is false automatically! (Is this homework where you're not allowed to use `not in`)?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
listt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
while listt:
    q1 = int(input("Enter number: "))
    if q1 in listt:
        listt.remove(q1)
        print("match")
    else:
        print("No match")
print("end")
```

Or you could do:

```
listt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
while listt:
    q1 = int(input("Enter number: "))
    if not q1 in listt:
        print("No match")
    else:
        print("Match")
        listt.remove(q1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use try and except  as alternative solution

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
while list:
        q1 = int(input("Enter number: "))
        try:
            list.remove(q1)
            print("match")
        except ValueError:
            print("No match")
```